# Duplicate class Testable found in modules junit-platform-commons-1.4.0.jar and kotlintest-core-3.3.0.jar

Tags: android, gradle, kotlintest

Hi I'm new in Android and I'm trying to run some test.

But when I try to use kotlintest I get the following error:

```
Duplicate class org.junit.platform.commons.annotation.Testable found in modules junit-platform-commons-1.4.0.jar (org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.4.0) and kotlintest-core-3.3.0.jar (io.kotlintest:kotlintest-core:3.3.0)
```

These are is my dependencies in gradle:

```
def grpcVersion = '1.22.1' // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'org.nield:kotlin-statistics:1.1.3'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.8"

    compileOnly "javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0"//This fixes the problem with Generated symbols

    // You need to build grpc-java to obtain these libraries below.
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:${grpcVersion}" // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:${grpcVersion}" // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:${grpcVersion}" // CURRENT_GRPC_VERSION
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'

    //Testing framework
    androidTestImplementation 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.3.0'

    //Mocking framework
    androidTestImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:{1.9.3}"
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be an issue with JUnit's Testable coming in 2 different versions from 2 different libraries. Perhaps excluding it from one of the dependencies work?

Comment: Could it be because I'm using: testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12' and  testImplementation 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.3.0'? I'm trying to remove kotlintest but I have another issue with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57325617/gradle-fails-failed-to-resolve-io-after-removing-kotlintest too